# Objective C selector memory managment (does this leak memory)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, selector

```
- (IBAction) someButtonCall {

        if(!someCondition) {
            someButtonCallBack = @selector(someButtonCall);
            [self presentModalViewController:someController animated:YES]; 
        } else
        ...
}

//Called from someController
- (void) someControllerFinished:(BOOL) ok {
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   if(ok) [self performSelector:someButtonCallBack];
   else ...
}
```

I'm wondering if the user keeps getting into the !someCondition clause if the selector is leaked by assigning a new selector each time (the code above is hypothetical and not what i'm doing).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
James Jones

Comment: Thanks everyone!!  I didn't think it did but I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this doesn't leak anything - you don't own the `SEL` values returned by `@selector()` and [`sel_registerName()`](http://tuvix.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-BCIGFJBB), the Objective-C runtime does.

Answer (score 0):

The [SEL](http://tuvix.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BAJDFBFC) type is simply a C string, so you won't have memory leaks whit re-assignations.

Answer (score 0):

This example does not leak memory.  `@selector()` is evaluated at compile time.  You could possibly leak a `SEL` variable, but not the selector itself.